# number of short and long signals

Tags: pine-script

I am creating a strategy that has long and short labels. Please tell me how can I make a sign that will display the number of short and long signals?
I can't even figure out how to do it. Can you help me?
for example

```
if close < ema(close, 100)
    label.new(bar_index, open , text = "SHORT", style = label.style_label_down, color = color.red ,textcolor = color.white)

if close > ema(close, 100)
    label.new(bar_index, open , text = "LONG", style = label.style_label_up, color = color.green , textcolor = color.white)
```

How can I create a label to the right of the whole chart that will display the number of short and long signals?

Answer (score 0):

There's two ways to interpret what you're asking.

1. Labels get thrown out, and you want the current amount rendered.
2. You want to track how many times a label was created, and you don't care if it is still rendered.

If 1, simply count the number of times the condition is true, then set a specific `max_labels_count` in your study or strategy. Here's a pseudo break-down:

```
study(max_labels_count=100)
var longSignals = 0
if close < ema(close,100)
    longSignals := min(longSignals + 1, 100)
    label.new(....
```

If 2, you don't need to use the max, you just track the number.

Then create a label and delete it each execution.

```
var label countsLabel = na
if not na(countsLabel)
    label.delete(countsLabel)
countsLabel = label.new(.........text=tostring(longSignals))
```

You could also just reset the position which might be better than deleting it.
For plotting to the right of the chart, you need to change the position to time-based as per the example in the documentation: https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Drawings.html?highlight=label#coordinates